# Is the hard-drive serial number with WMIService CHANGEABLE?

Tags: c#, vba

I use Hard-Drive Serial-Number check to register my products.

But I see that sometimes it's being changed.
Just 2 weeks after the client has activated the product, the hard-drive Serial-Num changed.

Is this property changeable? and if so, how when and why is it changed?

Here is the code i use in VB:

```
Dim WMIService As Object, Items As Object, SubItems As Object, temp
    
Set WMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & "." & "\root\cimv2")
    Set Items = WMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PhysicalMedia", , 48)
    For Each SubItems In Items
        temp = SubItems.SerialNumber
        If LenB(temp) Then Exit For
    Next
```

and the same thing i use in C#

```
using System.Management;

public string GetHDDSerial()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");

    foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
    {
        // get the hardware serial no.
        if (wmi_HD["SerialNumber"] != null)
            return wmi_HD["SerialNumber"].ToString();
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: i'm talking about an admin user, same user, same pc, same hard drive, but changed serial number.

Comment: Of course, there is also the obvious explanation: the HDD serial number changed because the HDD changed. Maybe it was defective, and the user replaced it, Maybe the user replaced it with a bigger or faster one. Maybe the user is using removable media and regularly swapping them around.

Comment: please check first comment

Comment: If the user deliberately change it, they could https://www.raymond.cc/blog/changing-or-spoofing-hard-disk-hardware-serial-number-and-volume-id/2/ but I'm not sure if it could change on its own

Comment: my client told me he didn't changed nothing like this manually. and in addition, as i see from my research here, this is not editable to the user.

Comment: Not sure about the order of the select-statement, but if you have more than one drive, your code returns the first one that has a serial number. Maybe user has more than one drive, or added a flash drive (USB)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from [FunThomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7599798/funthomas) and after a little troubleshooting with my client, i found out that he is using sometimes an external drive for more space, and when the external drive is plugged in - i'm getting a different HDD Serial-number.

**Now i have figured how to get the serial number from the current drive letter.**

here is the code for VB:

```
Dim WMIService As Object, DiskDrives As Object, Drive As Object, DiskPartitions As Object, Partition As Object, SerialNumber, currentDrive
currentDrive = Environ("HomeDrive")
Set WMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & "." & "\root\cimv2")
Set DiskPartitions = WMIService.ExecQuery("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='" & currentDrive & "'} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_DiskPartition")

For Each Partition In DiskPartitions
Set DiskDrives = WMIService.ExecQuery("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" & Partition.DeviceID & "'} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_DiskDrive")
    For Each Drive In DiskDrives
        Debug.Print "Caption: " & Drive.Caption, "Description: " & Drive.Description, "Name: " & Drive.Name, "Model: " & Drive.Model, "SerialNumber: " & Drive.SerialNumber
        SerialNumber = Drive.SerialNumber
    Next
Next
```